# Tell Rails to not cache on specific controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've googled for the past hour still couldn't find a command that tells Rails that it should not cache anything on that controller.

Not even a single fragment, every query should be performed ...

Any suggestions?

Notes:

**Rails: 4.0.9**

**caching:** [dalli](https://github.com/mperham/dalli)

**Reason:**

I use heavy Javascript within that controller -  when a user does an action Javascript fetches the newest result from a JSON feed.
example: 
root_url/events/all-events.json therefore it's important that Rails does not cache.

Comment: what version of rails are you using? Also what kind of caching do you have on in the application.

Comment: @C.J.Bordeleau Rails VErsion: 4.0.9; I use dalli for memcached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by adding a parameter to the url

just use :

```
 root_url/events/all-events.json?t=#{Time.now.to_i}
```

when you fetch it, and it will be fetched uncached

also, you can try try the action controller method [`expires_now`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ConditionalGet.html)

add it to a `:before_filter`

Comment: So basically I need some kind of random number generator for every request - when the url is not the same like the one before - Rails is going to fetch it?

Comment: exactly, thats one of the methods to get uncached files

Comment: BTW, better to also add some random to the timestamp, since its in seconds in ruby, or get it in miliseconds

Comment: Didn't work out for me - I fetch that stuff with Javascript. I created something like that: Math.random().toString(36).replace(/[^a-z]+/g, '').